# Mongodb - will $addToSet create the field?

Tags: mongodb

Will an array update using $addToSet create the field if it doesn't exist? In other words, if `field2` in the line below does not exist, will it be created by this command:

```
db.collection.update({id: <id>}, {<field2>: {$addToSet: <value>}})
```

Comment: You have a syntax error here. It must be {$addToSet: {<field2>: <value>}

Comment: thanks, I just threw it together to explain what I mean and didn't actually verify the syntax :)

Comment: This would have been super easy to test in the MongoDB console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will create. But the proper syntax is:

```
db.collection.update({id: <id>}, {$addToSet: {<field2>: <value>}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure and you can easily verify it yourself by typing something like this into your mongoshell

```
db.col.insert({_id : 1})
db.coll.update({_id : 1}, {$addToSet : {add : 4}})
```